# JPA persists already persisted Objects from a ManyToMany relationship

Tags: java, jpa, jpql

I have a @ManyToMany relationship between class A and class B : class A references a collection of class B instances, and this relationship is configured as CascadeType.ALL. So when a A is persisted with the entity manager, the B instances referenced by A are also persisted.

Both A and B have an ID declared with the GenerationType.IDENTITY strategy to use the auto_inc from the MySQL database.

The problem is :

1. I create a new A
2. I load some existing B objects from entityManager using JPQL
3. I add the B objects to A's collection of Bs

=> JPA tries to persist the B objects though they are already persisted (they just have been loaded).

I don't understand why it tries to persist them again, they have been properly loaded, and their auto generated id has been well loaded as well.

The ManyToMany declaration :

```
@ManyToMany(cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
@JoinTable(name = "ENTRY_ENTITIES", joinColumns =
@JoinColumn(name = "ENTRY", referencedColumnName = "ID"),
inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ENTITY", referencedColumnName = "ID"))
private List<Entity> entities;
```

The Query to load existing objects from database :

```
T result = (T) entityManager.createQuery("SELECT x FROM " + entityName + " x WHERE x.externalId='" + externalId + "'").getSingleResult();
```

The persisting :

```
UserTransaction transaction = getTransaction();
try {
    transaction.begin();
    entityManager.persist(entity);
    transaction.commit();
} catch (Throwable t) {
    Logger.getLogger(JpaDao.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, t);
}
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Show us the code of the entities, their mapping, and the code doing the persistence. Tell us which JPA engine you're using. Note that cacscade ALL on a ManyToMany is wrong: you don't want all the Bs of an A deleted when A is deleted, since the Bs are referenced by other As.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not absolutely sure that this is the cause of your problem, but you should include the whole thing inside of a transaction. Not just the persistence part:

```
start transaction
load B from DB
create new A
add B to A
commit transaction
```

As I said in my comments, you have other design and coding problems:

- CascadeType.ALL is wrong on a ManyToXxx association. You don't want all the Bs of an A deleted when you delete A, since those Bs are referenced by other As. This will lead to constraint violations (in the best case) or an inconsistent database (in the worst case, if you have no constraint defined)
- Don't use string concatenation in your queries. Use parameterized queries. This will avoid quoting problems and injection attacks: `SELECT x FROM A x WHERE x.externalId = :externalId`

Comment: Thanks, unfortunetly I can't put the loading and the persisting inside the same transaction, because first I load the Bs, then display them on a JSF page, and then when the user submits a form I create a A and persist it. So it's not in the same http request. Or sould I load them again a second time?

Comment: No, you shouldn't have to reload them. Which JPA engine are you using? Is the association bidirectional? Show us the full code of both entities and the code used to associate them.

Answer (score 1):

Those B entities may be part of another persistence context at the point in time that you are adding them to A.  Have you tried using the [merge operation](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#merge%28T%29) on the B entities after starting the transaction, **before** adding them to your A entity.